# SimpleSchema match any type but null

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

I'm planning to make a collection to hold different app-wide settings, like, say, amount of logged in users today, Google analytics tracking ID, etc. So I made a schema like this:

```
options_schema = new SimpleSchema({
    key: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    value: {
    },
    modified: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

Now the main problem is that I want `value` to be of any type: Number, String, Date, or even custom Objects. Though it has to be present, can't be `null`.

But of course it gets angry about not specifying the type. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Match patterns](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/matchpatterns) for your fields' `type` which allow you to do pretty much anything :

```
const notNullPattern = Match.Where(val => val !== null)
```

```
value : {
  type : notNullPattern
}
```

(See [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

Note that this will allow everything but `null`, including `undefined`.
Defining patterns this way allow you to use them everywhere in your application including [in `check`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check) :

```
check({
  key : 'the key',
  modified : Date.now(),
  value : {} // or [], 42, false, 'hello ground', ...
}, optionsSchema)
```

```
Match.test(undefined, notNullPattern) //true
Match.test({}, notNullPattern) //true
Match.test(null, notNullPattern) //false
```

A more general solution to exclude **one** value would simply be:

```
const notValuePattern =
  unwantedValue => Match.Where(val => val !== unwantedValue))
```

The use of which is similar to the above:

```
Match.test(42, notValuePattern(null)) // true
```

Note that due to the use of the [identity operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) it will notably [fail for `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN):

```
Match.test(NaN, notValuePattern(NaN)) // true :(
```

A solution could be:

```
const notValuePattern =
  unwantedValue => Match.Where(val => Number.isNaN(unwantedValue)?
    !Number.isNaN(val)
    : val !== unwantedValue
  )
```

---

Should you want a solution to exclude some specific values in a schema (kind of the contrary of [`Match.OneOf`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/matchpatterns)), you could use the following:

```
const notOneOfPattern = (...unwantedValues) => 
  Match.Where(val => !unwantedValues.includes(val)
)
```

This uses [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and the [`...` spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Use as follow:

```
Match.test(42, notOneOfPattern('self-conscious whale', 43)) // true
Match.test('tuna', notOneOfPattern('tyranny', 'tuna')) // false
Match.test('evil', notOneOfPattern('Plop', 'kittens')) // true

const disallowedValues = ['coffee', 'unicorns', 'bug-free software']
Match.test('bad thing', notOneOfPattern(...disallowedValues)) // true
```